# How to Remove Footers of LaTeX Beamer Templates?

Tags: latex, tex, beamer

I am using the "beamerthemesplit" template of the [Beamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_(LaTeX)) LaTeX package. This templates includes the author's name and the title of the presentation in the footer of all pages. Is anyone aware of any way to suppress this footer?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I got rid of the default footer, and inserted page numbers instead using the following commands.

```
%gets rid of bottom navigation bars
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

%gets rid of navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

Comment: Or use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}` (note the change from "page" to "frame") so the numbering counts frames instead of pages.

Comment: To completely remove footer, you need to also `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223200/how-to-completely-remove-footer-in-beamer

Answer (score 3):

I do not have the most direct answer for you as I do not use the beamerthemesplit template.
But for a recent presentation, I was tempted to decompose the themese a little.  So if you use this

```
\mode<presentation>
{
  \useoutertheme{default}   % empty
%  \useoutertheme{infolines}% simple but bland
%  \useoutertheme{split}    % ok if compress option used
%  \useoutertheme{shadow}   % way too much space used -- ok with option 'compress'
  %\useoutertheme{shadow}   
  %\setbeamercovered{transparent} % or whatever (possibly just delete it)
  %\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
}
```

you get via `default` a really empty setup. Adding `infolines` gives you a footer with three parts, you can study the code of that outer theme to just add parts. Likewiese with color themses -- I just experimented a little and eventually went back to a default theme.

Comment: This leads to a simple template with no footers. But, I'd like to customize the "beamerthemesplit" template.

Comment: Yes, so experiment, read the documentation, read the source of beamerthemesplit and try it. I hope what I posted above helps you in that regards -- as a start, try the commented-out parts one by one.